# made a typo doing a command and it gave me weird warnings

Tags: command-line

so I wrote 'sudo snap-store quit' but it should have been 'sudo snap-store --quit' instead, and it gave me a lot of weird warnings like '/system/ folder is predicated' 'mkdir: couldn't create new directory'. should I format my laptop? is it dangerous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's fine. You just told your computer to run the `snap-store` command, and without the `--quit` it thought you wanted to launch it. But because you prefixed with `sudo` it tried to launch the Snap Store graphical application as the `root` user.

I don't know what guide you followed, but to quit the snap store, you don't need sudo. Just `snap-store --quit` is fine. If you followed a guide somewhere online, let us know, and we can try and get that corrected. If it was just a mistake, don't worry about it, it's fine.

Comment: thanks! and the 'sudo' was my mistake, I didn't know we could run that command without it, thanks a lot.